# Instruction set and pseudo-command

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-architecture, assembly, disassembly

I use 'objdump' on linux in a variety of binaries and it returns their assembly. The commands that I receive is 'real' commands or pseudo-command? I have read that there are some commands which are a combination of other commands and they are called pseudo-commands. 
Is it true?
If yes, how can I get only 'real' commands from a executable?

Comment: Your terminology is incorrect.  A disassembly does not necessarily produce *"assembly"*, which allows label and variable names.  Unless there's a symbol table available, disassembly simply produces instructions in mnemonic form.  It's not *"commands"*, but instructions.

Comment: It's a bit confusing. Are there any reference for disassembly, instruction set for various architectures?

Answer (score 0):

On current x86- or ARM-based systems running Linux, the disassembled instructions will be real instructions.

Pseudo-operations are a convenience used when *creating* software, such as short sequences of instructions that are commonly used together, or instructions that are implemented in less-than-obvious ways.

For example, the instruction

```
mov eax, #0
```

which puts zero into register EAX, might be possible to implement in fewer bytes, and/or less time, as:

```
xor eax, eax
```

That exclusive-ORs register EAX with itself, which will always produce zero. An assembler thus might convert the easy-to-understand instruction into the smaller or faster form.